# Can we create a queue in form of list?

Tags: python, data-structures, queue

I have been learning the queue data structure recently. How do we actually create a queue? Can we just simply use a list and insert and remove items from the list? Or do I need to do something else? I have tried creating a queue class too. What is the correct method?

```
class Queue:
    
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.queue = []

    def IsEmpty(self):
        return len(self.queue) == self.capacity

    def IsFull(self):
        return len(self.queue) == 0

    def Enqueue(self, x):
        if len(self.queue) == self.capacity:
            return 'Queue overloaded'
        self.queue.insert(0, x)
        return f'{x} enqueued into queue.'

    def Dequeue(self):
        return f'{self.queue[0]} dequeued fron queue.'
        self.queue.pop(0)

    def GetFront(self):
        return self.queue[0]
    def GetBack(self):
        return self.queue[len(self.queue) - 1]
```

Comment: Just make sure to dequeue and enqueue from separate ends of the list!

Comment: Not sure what you're actually asking for, but the standard library has some decent queue implementations to offer.

Comment: You've got `IsEmpty` and `IsFull` backwards,  but yes, you can use a list. There are inefficiencies - inserting means all existing values have to be copied forward. You pushed and popped on one end so this is a LIFO queue. Most importantly, you don't have a way for a consumer to wait if nothing is available on the list.

Comment: @tdelaney Whoops! I reversed the two methods by mistake. How can we insert the values without copying the other items? And what does it mean by 'consumer to wait'?

Comment: If you insert at zero, the existing values need to be copied to 1 and higher. You can avoid this on a LIFO (last in first out) queue by doing the inserts at the end of the list. For a FIFO, you need to insert on one end and delete on the other, so  this shift is going to happen. This is trivial for small queues.

Comment: If you look at `queue.Queue` you'll notice that gets and puts have timeouts. The producer waits if the queue is full and the consumer waits if the queue is empty. I don't know if you need that functionality on your queue, its just a note about a common queue function.

Answer (score 0):

The common ways to implement a queue are basically:

1. Like an ArrayList, you use an array and reallocate a bigger one if it fills up.  Unlike an array list, you need to allow the elements in the queue to wrap around from the end to the start.  This is what java ArrayDeque does, and is probably the most common implementation.  There are variants that waste more memory but don't wrap around, and these are usually used if you sometimes have to pass parts of the queue to some other function as a contiguous region.
2. Use a singly-linked list, but also keep a pointer to the tail node so you can enqueue items quickly.  This is typically an intrusive list (i.e., you just and next pointers to objects you already have), or...
3. There's a particularly simple lock-free implementation of a thread-safe queue using a singly-linked list with an extra head node (and again a pointer to the tail node).  This is what Java's ConcurrentLinkedQueue uses.

Your implementation of a queue is none of these.  The python list is backed by an array like (1), but the first item is always at the start of the array.  The pop() operation can therefore take a long time, because all the other items have to be moved toward the start.

Comment: Ummm.... what exactly do you mean by wrap around in the Array List? And can you share some sample code in Python(if possible). I am just 13 and I don't have any teacher or coach to help me. Thanks! Great community!

Comment: Try this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okr-XE8yTO8